# Convert existing C++ (.h and .cpp) files to java for Android

Tags: java, c++, android

I am developing for Android under Eclipse. I have some c++ (.h and .cpp) files that I wish to use in my Android application. I have read [Programmming in C/C++ with the Java Native Interface](http://home.pacifier.com/~mmead/jni/cs510ajp/index.html) and now I know how to make .so file and import it to Android. But the main problem is that:

**Is there any tool that converts c++ (.h and .cpp) file to java style files which I can compile and create .so library ? I have heard about JNI - javah and javac can that tools help me and if they can so HOW ?**

---

**Edited:**

**javah is a useful tool that creates a C-style header file from a given class. The resulting header file describes the class file in C terms. Although it is possible to manually create the header file, this is almost always a bad idea. javah knows exactly how Java types and objects map into C types. For example, an int in Java maps to a long in C, and a long in Java maps to a 64-bit value, _int64, in native code. How to use this javah?**

**Anybody have expiarance of how to use functions that are implemented in .so library in android application ? If anybody have code examples or useful articles links please give.**

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't "convert C++ file to java style". You need to create a JNI wrapper around your existing C++ code. This JNI wrapper is actually C++ code that can be called by Java.

By wrapper I mean that you shouldn't have to modify your existing C++ code base. This wrapper, or better said this *binding* should generally be very thin. The wrapper code is only meant to expose existing functionalities, not to implement them. It is better to leave the implementation in the (portable) C++ code base.

If the code base isn't too large, then I recommend that you write this wrapper by hand, as explained in  [The JavaTM Native
Interface
Programmer's Guide and Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html)

Now, if you are trying to bind a large library, it may be problematic. So, in regard to tools, I haven't used that, but have a look at [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), and the relevant [SWIG Java documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Java.html#Java).

According to the homepage description, it's what you're asking for:

> SWIG is typically used to parse C/C++
>   interfaces and generate the 'glue
>   code' required for [Java, Python, PHP,
>   ...] to call into the C/C++ code.

javah can be useful in certain cases, but it's not what you ask for. It extracts JNI boiler plate code out of native declarations found in Java classes. Regarding javac, it's the Java compiler, that's irrelevant.

Comment: What it mean "You need to create a JNI wrapper around your existing C++ code" how ???

Comment: I've just updated the answer. I recommend that you read the JNI Programmer's Guide and write this wrapper code from scratch. By wrapper I mean JNI-compliant C++ functions, which simply call the "real" C++ functions.

Comment: It mean If I have cpp and h files I can create .dll file and when create a JNI wrapper and call the functions of my dll ???

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, you compile you existing C++ code into a library and you link the JNI wrapper with this library. Except that you don't create a "dll", you compile a separate static library using the BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY macro in Android.mk.

Comment: Okey .... one more question .... Now I Compile my .cpp and .h files and create .so Shared library !!! And for example in that .so lib I have functions F1, F2, F3, F4 Now I want to call F1 function in Adroid app what must I do ?

Comment: ViTo, your question now becomes too wide and fuzzy. I think that you need to go and buy good books about JNI and maybe also about C/C++.

Answer (score 3):

When developing for Android you are not limited to using the Java *language*. Why not use C++ directly? See e.g. the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html).

Comment: Yes I know. I have read the article Android NDK. But there is not C++ code if you read it you must know. Functions are something like this:

Comment: jstring Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz )
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !");
}

Comment: @ViTo Brothers Apoyan : The page linked to has samples explicitly written to demonstrate using JNI on Android. Look at the samples.

Comment: I have look ... At the samples, but I think that I cant write void func(int i, int j) { return i+j; } function like this in cpp file and create .so and import to android. Am I write ?

Comment: @ildjarn Have you ever write application for Android and include c/c++ files ?

Comment: @ViTo Brothers Apoyan : Yes, I have, but I have no idea what aspect of this you're not grasping, so I don't know how to help you beyond pointing you at the docs and samples.

Comment: OK !!! I have .h and .cpp files in witch I have many functions ... now I want to use that functions in my Android Application. Can you tell how I can Do that ?

Comment: @ViTo Brothers Apoyan : How do the NDK JNI samples not demonstrate **exactly** that? Look at the samples.

Comment: I have Cpp file in it int func(int i, int k, int j)
{
 return(i*j*k);
}
I create .so file using cd <ndk-root>/samples/hello-jni
<ndk_root>/ndk-build this commands after in Eclipse I write  public native int func(int i, int k, int j);
    
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
    } this but my program crashed

Comment: If you understand what is my problem can you help me and give example witch can help me ???

Comment: @ildjarn I have mfc/c++ based application that generate another executable file, now I want to modify application that can generate android executable