# compile ICS/JB camera application - native library jni-mosaic error

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-camera

I would like to use the Panorama mode that the ICS/JB camera application has.
I've downloaded the source code (with resources) and managed to solve all code compilation errors but as soon as I start the application on my device (running JB), I get this error:

```
10-25 14:42:53.617: E/AndroidRuntime(23147): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 2586
10-25 14:42:53.617: E/AndroidRuntime(23147): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.app.camera.panorama.MosaicRenderer.reset:(IIZ)V
10-25 14:42:53.617: E/AndroidRuntime(23147):    at com.app.camera.panorama.MosaicRenderer.reset(Native Method)
10-25 14:42:53.617: E/AndroidRuntime(23147):    at com.app.camera.panorama.MosaicRendererSurfaceViewRenderer.onSurfaceChanged(MosaicRendererSurfaceViewRenderer.java:49)
10-25 14:42:53.617: E/AndroidRuntime(23147):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505)
10-25 14:42:53.617: E/AndroidRuntime(23147):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

I do have a libjni-mosaic lib, located in armeabi-v7a/armeabi/x86 and it seems to load it fine but it probably doesn't contain the methods the MosaicRenderer implements.

I also tried compiling the CyanogenMod camera app https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Camera/tree/ics but I get the same error...

The camera itself works, for stills and video recording but as soon as I change to panorama mode, it crashes.

Can anyone maybe point me to the right jni-mosaic lib or maybe to what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to do something in order to make my app use the JNI/SO files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You moved the Java class MosaicRenderer to package `com.app.camera.panorama`, but the `mosaic_renderer_jni.cpp` file still has the native methods refer to `com.android.camera.panorama`, like

```
JNIEXPORT void Java_com_android_camera_panorama_MosaicRenderer_reset(
```

You should change the function names in the native code to reflect the new package name, e.g.

```
JNIEXPORT void Java_com_app_camera_panorama_MosaicRenderer_reset(
```

Comment: thanks! :) I'm not sure that's the problem because I tried again and this time, I left the MosaicRenderer in com.android.camera.panorama and I get the same error but I'll make sure on Sunday and if it is the issue, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks again but unfortunately I just checked the mosaic_renderer_jni.cpp file (compiled from CyanogenMod sources) and it has the right path (com.android.camera.panorama). The com.app.camera.panorama package was for my test app. I'll try to follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949557/convert-existing-c-h-and-cpp-files-to-java-for-android to create the right so file.

Comment: You should check the symbols exported from your `.so` with `nm` command. Maybe your build got `Java_com_android_camera_panorama_MosaicRenderer_reset` exported with C++ mangling.

Comment: Thank you for replying! no new log. I assume you're right as I do use a libjni-mosaic library I found on the web, which is probably using a different package. I got the jni folder from CM sources now and I'm building a new libjni-mosaic.so (cygwin+ndk) with my application's package as you suggested.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as accepted as it probably the solution to my question. I am now stuck with a different issue but that requires another question. Thanks for helping.

Comment: btw, if you have time and want to, I would love if you can look at my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108603/ndk-error-trying-to-build-cyanogenmod-camera-application

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is still interested in building Google's native camera app,I suggest you this repository https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera2/ It doesn't require building all android OS code.It helped me very much.